PHP is not reading .env file
I am using PHP with PDO to connect to my database.
I want to start using environment variables, so I used the following terminal command:
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv

My .env file now contains the following values:
DATABASE_HOSTNAME=db
DATABASE_NAME=myDb
DATABASE_USERNAME=user 
DATABASE_PASSWORD=test 

My test db connection file looks like this:
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$host = getenv("DATABASE_HOSTNAME");
$dbname = getenv("DATABASE_NAME");
$dbuser = getenv("DATABASE_USERNAME");
$dbpass = getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD");

try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;port=3306", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbc->SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Conneciton failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  }  
?> 

I am getting the below error:
Conneciton failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I added this code to the test db connection file:
echo "X" . getenv('X');
echo "host is " . $host;

In the terminal, I enter:  php test.php
And it echos out the following:
Xhost is %

Here is a screenshot:

What am I doing wrong?

Probably relevant in your case: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#putenv-and-getenv.  Tl;dr, don't use getenv and use $_ENV[...] instead.

if you are using php with Apache as a webServer I'd use the builtin env variables available there instead of an external library in php. this way there are no files .env around

Not related to your problem, but getenv returns false if the variable doesn't exist, and when you concatenate that with the string X it gets converted to the empty string "". Based on your rep I'm guessing you knows this, but I just wanted to warn you that this can lead to a certain madness when debugging, especially if having empty ENV variables (for whatever reason) is something that you need to support.

@Matthew - I made that change and now it works.  Side note: this is the part of programming that irks me; the constant (and sometimes unnecessary) changes in the syntax, deprecations, etc.  Although I understand it's part of the field of technology, I just find it extremely annoying.  I should've been a chef.  By the way - did you want to post an answer?  I'll accept it.

It's good job security, half your time spent is fixing stuff that already worked.

This is due to getenv and putenv not being populated by default with the Dotenv library.
Should use $_ENV instead to read the variables if using the createImmutable function, otherwise check out the docs at https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#putenv-and-getenv
